# Earthing when two objects need to be earthed

Tags: transformer, grounding

I recently bought a ‘Push To WAIT’ unit from the Highways Agency. It has a transformer that converts 240V to 48V which goes to the unit.

The trouble is, the transformer and the Push to wait Unit both have earth wires on them, but I can't figure out how to earth these properly (without harming myself.)

I understand that the transformer earth Wire has to go into the plug socket but where do I earth the actual unit to?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

All the earth connections should be to mains earth, as the transformer goes inside the unit there is still a risk that the mains wiring could fail to the casing of the device.

Comment: What happens if i leave the Transformer out of the unit and seperate?

Comment: Still not a bad idea to have it grounded unless you have a reason no to, as metal being tied to mains ground rarely causes issues. 

to directly answer the question, you would not need it, depending on your country they may still want it.